# XPath: Extract text between elements based on two XPath paths

Tags: xpath

The HTML looks as follows

```
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>
                <p>sample-text here p1 </p>
                <p>sample-text here p2</p>
                <p>sample-text here p3</p>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                <span>
                    <p>sample-text here p4</p>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                <div>
                    <span>
                        <p>sample-text here p5</p>
                        <p>sample-text here p6</p>
                        <p>sample-text here p7</p>
                        <p>sample-text here p8</p>
                        <p>sample-text here p9</p>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I have two XPath paths as follows

```
/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/p[3]/text()
```

AND

```
/div[1]/div[3]/p[1]/div[1]/span[1]/p[3]/text()
```

the first one gets '**sample-text here p3**' and the second one gets '**sample-text here p7**'

Now, my goal is to actually get the text of all elements between these two paths (including these two elements)

```
/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/p[3] AND /div[1]/div[3]/p[1]/div[1]/span[1]/p[3]
```

The expected result would be 
**sample-text here p3 sample-text here p4 sample-text here p5 sample-text here p6 sample-text here p7**

I looked into the XPath Axes and Operators, But, not really sure, how those can be used for this context. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

**EDIT:**
I edited this question including the sample HTML to cover a little more different structure across all divs. The intent is to be able to use those XPaths and rather not depending on the structure of the document, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `axes` here, just use `position()`

```
(*//span/p)[position() >= 3 and position() <= 7]
```

using the full `xpath`, based on your sample `xml`

```
(/div/div/span/p)[position() >= 3 and position() <= 7]
```

Comment: I get your answer, But, how if this HTML is more complex where the structure is really unknown, But all that I have is those two XPath paths? Is there a more generic way to handle that case? I appreciate your response.

Comment: specify the full xpath, just to be sure.

Comment: I will edit the question to make it sort of more specific

Comment: @METAL, I edited the question to cover a general use case, sorry for lack of clarity in the question.

Comment: @Vsoma, i think this is the only way `(*//span/p)[position() >= 3 and position() <= 7]`